# Complex form with nested attributes, how to add relation to existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have complex form with nested forms
Product <- OneToMany -> Variant(:product_id) <- OneToMany -> Asset(:variant_id)
All in the single form...
I have nested_form gem for adding new items on client side.
This all works well up untill Assets...
Assets created by uploading files using Ajax... so assets already in the database when i create new product.
So Product(and variants for it) is new and needs to be created in the database, but assets already exist..

The question is how to link new Variant to existing Asset in a product creation form...

And the problem not in the javascript to add nested fields... But in what fields should i add to make it work...
Currently i'm adding

```
<input class="id" id="product_variants_attributes_1406469924735_assets_attributes_1406469935999_id" name="product[variants_attributes][1406469924735][assets_attributes][1406469935999][id]" type="hidden" value="17">
```

But that's not working, because Rails searches for asset within the scope of the Variant... wich does not exist yet and ofc there is no asset in that Variant with this id even when variant exists... So i'm getting this error upon submission:
`Couldn't find Asset with ID=17 for Variant with ID=`

Is there any magical html code that will be translated to `variant.assets << Asset.find(id)` on the server side...?

Is it actually possible to manage OneToMany relation with existing items using forms? Or should i convert my relation to ManyToMany so i will be working with "join table" model...